# I'm new to Unity3D , Getting compiler errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I'm making a stickman game I added a balance script.

But it shows a compiler error "The variable of rb has not been assigned".

Can u please tell me how to assign a variable?

Here's the code-

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rb.MoveRotation(Mathf.LerpAngle(rb.rotation, targetRotation, force * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
}
```

Comment: Assuming that rb is a `Rigidbody` component, you need to assign it either in code or in the inspector. If the field is private and not serialized, you need to assign it using [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). If it is serialized or public, you can drag the reference in the inspector. For your use case, you would set it most likely in `Awake` or `Start` and set it as `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`. If the script is not on the same object as the component, then this line would change. Same if the rigidbody is 2D.

Comment: This is either not your actual code or not the actual error .. `rb` can not be a "variable" in the code you provide. A variable is declared inside of the same method. And for a field there would be no compile time error "The variable of rb has not been assigned" but rather a runtime `NullReferenceException` .. so please share your actual code!

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't to use a Rigidbody you need to get the component from the GameObject and in your case make the actual Rigidbody variable you want to use.

Your code should look like that:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        //Fetch the Rigidbody from the GameObject with this script attached
        rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb.MoveRotation(.....);
    }
}
```